# Is there any php script that using regex or other methods to clean html pages?

Tags: php, regex, static-pages

Here is my idea, I want to create a tool that can create static html pages, out of php pages, perhaps generated by a cms.

Then I want to use some kind of regex, or clean tool, to reorganize the html to generate a cleaner, more standardized, yslow compliant html pages.

I may asking for what does not exist, if so, any suggestions for a close cousin solution?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you asking for a cmdline tool like `tidy` perhaps?

Comment: Maybe something like mod_tidy would do this for you http://mod-tidy.sourceforge.net/ if you are using Apache

Comment: This has to be a php script or class, to be integrated with the cms.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Tidy: http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php

Works great for cleaning up html.

Not regex but an extension.